# Tailwind animate-spin not working on mobile

Tags: reactjs, github, tailwind-css, github-pages

I'm running into a problem where an animation I'm doing on a group within my SVG is displaying properly on the browser, but not on mobile. I'm using React for this and deploying it on GitHub Pages for now. I've installed Tailwind using the CLI. I haven't been able to find the solution in my search, but I'm new to this! Here's my code:

```
<svg className={location.pathname === "/" ? "w-20" : "sm:w-20 w-12"} version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <path d="m165 577.68v502.32c0 3.9766 1.582 7.793 4.3945 10.605s6.6289 4.3945 10.605 4.3945h840c3.9766 0 7.793-1.582 10.605-4.3945s4.3945-6.6289 4.3945-10.605v-504c49.824-31.371 87.34-78.93 106.24-134.69 18.902-55.762 18.039-116.33-2.4453-171.53-20.484-55.199-59.336-101.67-110.04-131.61-50.699-29.934-110.16-41.512-168.39-32.789-58.227 8.7266-111.68 37.223-151.38 80.703-39.699 43.48-63.227 99.297-66.633 158.08h-84.84c-3.7305-58.719-27.531-114.37-67.414-157.63-39.883-43.258-93.422-71.496-151.64-79.977-58.223-8.4805-117.59 3.3047-168.16 33.391-50.566 30.082-89.254 76.633-109.59 131.85-20.328 55.215-21.059 115.74-2.0742 171.43s56.535 103.16 106.36 134.46zm136.68-444c60.094 0 117.72 23.859 160.23 66.336 42.508 42.477 66.406 100.09 66.449 160.18 0.042969 60.094-23.777 117.74-66.223 160.28-42.445 42.535-100.05 66.477-160.14 66.562-60.094 0.085938-117.76-23.695-160.32-66.109-42.566-42.418-66.547-100-66.676-160.09 0.0625-60.102 23.965-117.72 66.465-160.21 42.496-42.5 100.12-66.402 160.21-66.465zm340.68 240c3.7344 65.395 32.316 126.89 79.895 171.91 47.582 45.016 110.57 70.145 176.07 70.254 36.879-0.16406 73.281-8.3555 106.68-24v293.16h-810v-291c33.398 15.645 69.801 23.836 106.68 24 65.789-0.12891 129.02-25.492 176.66-70.855 47.641-45.367 76.066-107.28 79.418-172.98zm482.64-15c0 60.121-23.883 117.78-66.395 160.29-42.508 42.508-100.17 66.391-160.29 66.391-60.121 0-117.78-23.883-160.29-66.391-42.508-42.512-66.391-100.17-66.391-160.29 0-60.117 23.883-117.78 66.391-160.29 42.512-42.512 100.17-66.395 160.29-66.395 39.832 0.042969 78.953 10.57 113.43 30.52 34.477 19.953 63.094 48.633 82.973 83.148s30.324 73.66 30.281 113.49zm-120 705.84h-49.68v-80.52c0-3.9766-1.582-7.793-4.3945-10.605s-6.6289-4.3945-10.605-4.3945h-12v-54h77.039zm-104.4 0v-66h24.719v66zm-312.6 0.48047v-66h24v66zm-312.96 0v-66h24.961v66zm468.96-66h24.719v66h-24.719zm-312.96 0h24.961v66h-24.84zm-236.16-84h77.039v54h-12 0.003906c-4.0234-0.0625-7.8984 1.4883-10.766 4.3086-2.8633 2.8203-4.4766 6.6719-4.4766 10.691v81h-49.68zm120 54h-12v-54h125.64v54h-12c-4.0391-0.097656-7.9492 1.4414-10.84 4.2656-2.8906 2.8203-4.5195 6.6914-4.5195 10.734v81h-72v-81c0-3.9375-1.5469-7.7148-4.3086-10.523-2.7617-2.8047-6.5156-4.4141-10.453-4.4766zm156 0h-12v-54h126.12v54h-12c-4.0391-0.097656-7.9492 1.4414-10.84 4.2656-2.8906 2.8203-4.5195 6.6914-4.5195 10.734v81h-72v-81c0-3.9375-1.5469-7.7148-4.3086-10.523-2.7617-2.8047-6.5156-4.4141-10.453-4.4766zm156 0h-12v-54h126.6v54h-12c-4.0391-0.097656-7.9492 1.4414-10.84 4.2656-2.8906 2.8203-4.5234 6.6914-4.5195 10.734v81h-72v-81c0-3.9375-1.5469-7.7148-4.3086-10.523-2.7617-2.8047-6.5156-4.4141-10.453-4.4766zm156 0h-12v-54h127.08v54h-12c-4.043-0.097656-7.9492 1.4414-10.84 4.2656-2.8945 2.8203-4.5234 6.6914-4.5195 10.734v81h-72v-81c0-3.9375-1.5469-7.7148-4.3086-10.523-2.7617-2.8047-6.5156-4.4141-10.453-4.4766z" />
    <g>
      <g className="animate-spin direction-reverse origin-[25%_30%] fill-blue-700">
        <path d="m207.84 360.84c0 24.887 9.8867 48.758 27.484 66.355 17.598 17.598 41.469 27.484 66.355 27.484 24.887 0 48.758-9.8867 66.355-27.484 17.598-17.598 27.484-41.469 27.484-66.355 0-24.887-9.8867-48.758-27.484-66.355s-41.469-27.484-66.355-27.484c-24.879 0.03125-48.727 9.9297-66.32 27.52-17.59 17.594-27.488 41.441-27.52 66.32zm93.84-63.84c16.934 0 33.168 6.7266 45.141 18.699 11.973 11.973 18.699 28.211 18.699 45.141 0 16.93-6.7266 33.168-18.699 45.141-11.973 11.973-28.207 18.699-45.141 18.699-16.93 0-33.168-6.7266-45.141-18.699-11.973-11.973-18.699-28.211-18.699-45.141 0-16.93 6.7266-33.168 18.699-45.141 11.973-11.973 28.211-18.699 45.141-18.699z" />
        <path d="m301.68 246.84c3.9805 0 7.793-1.582 10.605-4.3945 2.8164-2.8125 4.3945-6.6289 4.3945-10.605v-52.68c0-5.3594-2.8594-10.312-7.5-12.992-4.6406-2.6797-10.359-2.6797-15 0-4.6406 2.6797-7.5 7.6328-7.5 12.992v52.68c0 3.9766 1.582 7.793 4.3945 10.605s6.6289 4.3945 10.605 4.3945z" />
        <path d="m461.76 448.08-44.039-28.922-0.003906 0.003906c-3.2695-2.7734-7.5703-4.0195-11.816-3.4141-4.2461 0.60156-8.0312 2.9961-10.398 6.5703-2.3672 3.5781-3.0898 7.9961-1.9844 12.141 1.1016 4.1445 3.9297 7.6172 7.7617 9.543l44.039 28.922c2.4844 1.5469 5.3516 2.3789 8.2812 2.3984 4.3008-0.046874 8.375-1.9375 11.188-5.1953 2.8164-3.2539 4.0938-7.5625 3.5156-11.824-0.58203-4.2656-2.9648-8.0742-6.543-10.461z" />
        <path d="m137.28 468.84c2.8086 4.207 7.5391 6.7305 12.598 6.7188 2.8906-0.035156 5.7148-0.86328 8.1602-2.3984l44.039-29.16c3.4531-2.125 5.8945-5.5547 6.7773-9.5078 0.88281-3.957 0.125-8.0977-2.0938-11.488-2.2227-3.3867-5.7227-5.7344-9.6992-6.5039s-8.0977 0.10547-11.422 2.4219l-44.039 29.156c-3.3516 2.1602-5.6953 5.5742-6.5078 9.4766-0.8125 3.9023-0.023438 7.9688 2.1875 11.285z" /> 
      </g>
      <g className="animate-spin direction-reverse origin-[75%_30%] fill-blue-700">
        <path d="m804 359.16c0 24.887 9.8867 48.758 27.484 66.355s41.469 27.484 66.355 27.484c24.887 0 48.758-9.8867 66.355-27.484 17.598-17.598 27.484-41.469 27.484-66.355 0-24.887-9.8867-48.758-27.484-66.355-17.598-17.598-41.469-27.484-66.355-27.484-24.879 0.03125-48.727 9.9297-66.32 27.52-17.59 17.594-27.488 41.441-27.52 66.32zm157.68 0c0 16.93-6.7266 33.168-18.699 45.141-11.973 11.973-28.211 18.699-45.141 18.699-16.93 0-33.168-6.7266-45.141-18.699-11.973-11.973-18.699-28.211-18.699-45.141 0-16.93 6.7266-33.168 18.699-45.141 11.973-11.973 28.211-18.699 45.141-18.699 17.004-0.097656 33.348 6.582 45.418 18.562 12.07 11.98 18.871 28.273 18.902 45.277z" />
        <path d="m898.32 245.16c3.9766 0 7.793-1.582 10.605-4.3945s4.3945-6.6289 4.3945-10.605v-52.68c0-5.3594-2.8594-10.312-7.5-12.992-4.6406-2.6797-10.359-2.6797-15 0-4.6406 2.6797-7.5 7.6328-7.5 12.992v52.68c0 3.9766 1.5781 7.793 4.3945 10.605 2.8125 2.8125 6.625 4.3945 10.605 4.3945z" />
        <path d="m1014.4 417.36c-3.3359-2.1445-7.3789-2.8984-11.262-2.0898-3.8867 0.80859-7.2969 3.1094-9.4961 6.4102-2.1797 3.3281-2.9492 7.3828-2.1367 11.273 0.80859 3.8945 3.1289 7.3047 6.457 9.4883l44.039 28.922v-0.003906c2.4102 1.625 5.25 2.5039 8.1602 2.5195 4.3633 0.042969 8.5273-1.8164 11.406-5.0938 2.8828-3.2773 4.1914-7.6484 3.5938-11.969-0.60156-4.3242-3.0547-8.168-6.7227-10.535z" />
        <path d="m782.28 417.36-44.039 28.922h-0.003907c-3.332 2.2031-5.6562 5.6367-6.4648 9.5469-0.80859 3.9141-0.039063 7.9883 2.1484 11.332 2.1758 3.332 5.5977 5.6484 9.5 6.4375 3.9023 0.78906 7.957-0.015625 11.258-2.2383l44.039-28.922v0.003906c4.3164-3.0078 6.7422-8.0508 6.3945-13.301-0.34766-5.2461-3.418-9.9258-8.0898-12.336-4.6719-2.4141-10.266-2.2031-14.742 0.55469z" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <path d="m423 618.72v202.56c0 3.9766 1.582 7.793 4.3945 10.605s6.6289 4.3945 10.605 4.3945h324c3.9766 0 7.793-1.582 10.605-4.3945s4.3945-6.6289 4.3945-10.605v-202.56c0-3.9766-1.582-7.793-4.3945-10.605s-6.6289-4.3945-10.605-4.3945h-324c-3.9766 0-7.793 1.582-10.605 4.3945s-4.3945 6.6289-4.3945 10.605zm324 187.56-294 0.003906v-172.56h294z" />
    <path d="m530.4 768.96c12.988 0 25.441-5.1602 34.621-14.34 9.1836-9.1836 14.34-21.637 14.34-34.621s-5.1562-25.438-14.34-34.621c-9.1797-9.1797-21.633-14.34-34.621-14.34-12.984 0-25.438 5.1602-34.617 14.34-9.1836 9.1836-14.34 21.637-14.34 34.621s5.1562 25.438 14.34 34.621c9.1797 9.1797 21.633 14.34 34.617 14.34zm0-67.922c5.0312 0 9.8516 2 13.41 5.5547 3.5547 3.5547 5.5508 8.3789 5.5508 13.406s-1.9961 9.8516-5.5508 13.406c-3.5586 3.5547-8.3789 5.5547-13.41 5.5547-5.0273 0-9.8477-2-13.406-5.5547-3.5547-3.5547-5.5508-8.3789-5.5508-13.406s1.9961-9.8516 5.5508-13.406c3.5586-3.5547 8.3789-5.5547 13.406-5.5547z" />
    <path d="m669.6 768.96c12.984 0 25.438-5.1602 34.617-14.34 9.1836-9.1836 14.34-21.637 14.34-34.621s-5.1562-25.438-14.34-34.621c-9.1797-9.1797-21.633-14.34-34.617-14.34-12.988 0-25.441 5.1602-34.621 14.34-9.1836 9.1836-14.34 21.637-14.34 34.621s5.1562 25.438 14.34 34.621c9.1797 9.1797 21.633 14.34 34.621 14.34zm0-67.922c5.0273 0 9.8477 2 13.406 5.5547 3.5547 3.5547 5.5508 8.3789 5.5508 13.406s-1.9961 9.8516-5.5508 13.406c-3.5586 3.5547-8.3789 5.5547-13.406 5.5547-5.0312 0-9.8516-2-13.41-5.5547-3.5547-3.5547-5.5508-8.3789-5.5508-13.406s1.9961-9.8516 5.5508-13.406c3.5586-3.5547 8.3789-5.5547 13.41-5.5547z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

On my browser, everything is running OK — the group spins counterclockwise and maintains its position. On mobile, the group is static. You can check out the animation here: https://cadienlake.github.io/react-tailwind-portfolio

Comment: It's working on mobile for me

Comment: On which browsers and platforms are you seeing this issue?